# Backtracking and Recursion Clarification

Tags: algorithm, recursion, backtracking

Could someone point out differences, benefits, complexities wrt both the code snippets? Are both of them backtracking or first one is recursion and second one is backtracking?

Sources:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-permutations-of-a-string-in-java/
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-to-print-all-permutations-of-a-given-string/

```
Code 1
========
public class GFG { 
    static void printPermutn(String str, String ans) 
    { 
        if (str.length() == 0) { 
            System.out.print(ans + " "); 
            return; 
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) { 
            char ch = str.charAt(i);            
            String ros = str.substring(0, i) +  
                         str.substring(i + 1); 
            printPermutn(ros, ans + ch); 
        } 
    } 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String s = "abb"; 
        printPermutn(s, ""); 
    } 
} 
Code 2
========
public class Permutation { 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str = "ABC"; 
        int n = str.length(); 
        Permutation permutation = new Permutation(); 
        permutation.permute(str, 0, n - 1); 
    } 
    private void permute(String str, int l, int r) 
    { 
        if (l == r) 
            System.out.println(str); 
        else { 
            for (int i = l; i <= r; i++) { 
                str = swap(str, l, i); 
                permute(str, l + 1, r); 
                str = swap(str, l, i); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    public String swap(String a, int i, int j) 
    { 
        char temp; 
        char[] charArray = a.toCharArray(); 
        temp = charArray[i]; 
        charArray[i] = charArray[j]; 
        charArray[j] = temp; 
        return String.valueOf(charArray); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both code snippets implement some form of recursion. You can tell that since both have code with a base case, and a function that calls itself. You can see more [documentation on recursion here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/). Recursion is, at its most basic form, a function that calls itself until a condition is met.

A recursion example for calculating the factorial is here:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if (n < = 1) // base case
        return 1;
    else    
        return n*fact(n-1);    
}
```

Here, if n = 1, just return a 1. Otherwise, return the number you entered * the number - 1 factorial.
So if you entered `10`
`return 10 * factorial (9) = 10 * 9 * factorial (8) = 10 * 9 * 8 * factorial (7)` etc etc until you get

```
10 * 9 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * factorial (0) = 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Additionally, both also implement backtracking, [since backtracking is simply finding some set (sometimes a subset, sometimes all) solutions to a problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking#cite_note-1)